# Python Tkinter: obtain tree node information

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tree, tkinter

Python 2.7 Linux

I am only using idlelib.TreeWidget to create a tree in Tkinter.Canvas, nothing else.

How do I go about getting the information of the selected tree node (eg. name)? I need to access this information later.

I am able to call a function when the Canvas is selected / double-clicked, but not sure how with the tree nodes:

```
self.canvas.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.onSave)
```

Please run the following code (Note that there are 2 trees, 1 tree in each Canvas):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH, Canvas
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from idlelib.TreeWidget import TreeItem, TreeNode

class DomTreeItem(TreeItem):
   def __init__(self, node):
      self.node = node
   def GetText(self):
      node = self.node
      if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
         return node.nodeName
      elif node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
         return node.nodeValue
   def IsExpandable(self):
      node = self.node
      return node.hasChildNodes()
   def GetSubList(self):
      parent = self.node
      children = parent.childNodes
      prelist = [DomTreeItem(node) for node in children]
      itemlist = [item for item in prelist if item.GetText().strip()]
      return itemlist

data = '''
<angel>
 <digital_core>
  <radio_top>d</radio_top>
  <uart_top>e</uart_top>
 </digital_core>
 <digital_core>
  <c>f</c>
 </digital_core>
</angel>
'''
class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent, background = "white")
      self.parent = parent

      # Maximize window
      self.screenWidth = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth() - 5
      self.screenHeight = self.parent.winfo_screenheight() - 110
      self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight, 0, 0))
      self.parent.resizable(0, 0)

      dom = parseString(data)
      item = DomTreeItem(dom.documentElement)
      self.canvas = Canvas(self, bg = "cyan")
      self.canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 0, rowspan = 2, sticky = 'NSWE', padx = 5, pady = 5)
      node = TreeNode(self.canvas, None, item)
      node.update()

      self.canvas2 = Canvas(self, bg = "yellow")
      self.canvas2.grid(column = 1, row = 0, rowspan = 2, sticky = 'NSWE', padx = 5, pady = 5)
      node2 = TreeNode(self.canvas2, None, item)
      node2.update()

      parent.configure(bg = "black")
      self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True, padx = 20, pady = 20)

def main():
   root = Tk()
   Application(root)
   root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DanGar's answer was helpful, but not exactly what I want.

TreeItem already has built-in functions GetSelectedIconName and OnDoubleClick, so I used it in my modified class to get the name of selection:

```
class DomTreeItem(TreeItem):
   def __init__(self, node):
      self.node = node
   def GetText(self):
      node = self.node
      if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
         return node.nodeName
      elif node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
         return node.nodeValue
   def IsExpandable(self):
      node = self.node
      return node.hasChildNodes()
   def GetSubList(self):
      parent = self.node
      children = parent.childNodes
      prelist = [DomTreeItem(node) for node in children]
      itemlist = [item for item in prelist if item.GetText().strip()]
      return itemlist
   def GetSelectedIconName(self):
      print self.node.nodeName
   def OnDoubleClick(self):
      print "double-clicked"
```

Answer (score 2):

The most direct approach I have seen is accessing the fields of the `TreeNode` to retrieve content passed into the `TreeNode` constructor.

For instance,

```
node.parent
node.canvas
node.item
```

To get the text from the `DomTreeItem`, you can do

```
node.item.GetText()
```

You can also get additional information by looking at the methods in

```
dir(node.item)
```

Comment: Sure, but how to trigger the function when a node is selected?

Comment: I am able to call a function when the Canvas is double-clicked, but not sure how with the tree nodes